# For $p$ prime, the group $R_p$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

The group $R_p$ is the group of all integers $q$ with $1\leq q \leq p-1$, where the greatest common factor of $p$ and $q$ is 1.

I'm aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989451/proving-that-the-multiplicative-group-mod-p-p-is-prime-is-cyclic) proof but I was thinking of an alternate route. What if I could define a mapping from $R_p$ to $\mathbb{Z_{p-1}}$ and show that it is an isomorphism. Then the "cyclicity" of $\mathbb{Z_{p-1}}$ carries over to $R_p$. How could I define such a mapping? Is it possible?

Comment: I assume $p$ is prime, right? $R_p$ has $p - 1$ elements and $\mathbb{Z}_{p - 2}$ has $p - 2$ elements, so no isomorphism between them exists.

Comment: Correct, made the change.

Comment: @JacopoStifani how is $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ defined? In the standard definition, this is trivial

Comment: Your link is to a proof that uses $\sum_{d|n}\phi (d)=n.$ Would you like to see an elementary proof that does not use it?

Comment: In number-theoretic language, we need to show that there is a primitive root mod $p$, and then the discrete logarithm does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Finding an isomorphism $R_p \to \mathbb Z_{p-1}$ is the same as finding a generator of $R_p$. If you are this point, you have already shown that $R_p$ is cyclic. There is no "totally trivial" proof of this fact. The proof will always be the same work as the proof that any finite subgroup of $K^*$ (for a field $K$) is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

The "identity" map works. Map the integer $a$ to the coset $a+p\mathbb{Z}$, which is clearly an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes indeed, i meant $\mathbb{Z_{p-1}}$.

Comment: @JacopoStifani  does this do it

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z_{p-1}}$ has order $p$ and $R_p$ has order $p-1$. How will this work?